# ActiveMQ message content is not cleared after the message is sent

Tags: java, memory-leaks, activemq-classic, message-queue

I have java application in which there are a sender and receiver and ActiveMQ Queue
the sender creates messages and sends them to the Queue and the consumer consumes the messages from there. 
each time I send a message it gets serialized and its content holds `ByteSequence` of the message , and the Queue gets that message and the consumer consumes it but, I found that each time I send a message to the Queue, the `ByteSequence` is not cleared from the memory and eventually I get `OutOfMemoryException`

shouldn't the message be deleted from the producer after it has been sent to the Queue?

thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you can't do that for some reason then at the very least provide the Java code for your sender/receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it appears that the Q is using the prefetch default value of 1000 which caused the consumer to get OOM exception because the processing time of each message was too long and the prefetch was only getting filled quickly